# GcmNetworkManager maximum number of scheduled tasks

Tags: android, google-play-services, gcm-network-manager, gcmtaskservice

I am scheduling OneOff tasks with the GcmNetworkManager at a rate of one every 30 seconds. All of these tasks will retry if they fail. I am wondering what will happen if the user then places their phone in airplane mode for a long period of time and these tasks queue up. Will some tasks eventually be thrown out?

Comment: This smells of malpractice. What are you trying to do in those tasks?

Comment: Each task is a network request. I understand this case would more appropriately be a periodic task, but I am more asking hypothetically, how GcmNetworkManager would handle a very large queue of tasks.